# A question on permutation and combination with the application of elementry coordinate geometry

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many shortest ways can we reach from the point (0, 0, 0) to point (3, 7, 11) in space where the movement is possible only along the x-axis, y-axis, and z-axis or parallel to them and change of axes is permitted only at integral points? (An integral point is one, which has its coordinate as integer.)

I am facing problem in interpreting this question can anyone please help me in getting the solution.

**Answer given in book**
$(^{21}C_3).(^{18}C_7)$

Comment: Please show what have you tried and where are you stuck

Comment: Problem needs clarification: [1] : typo : "along the x-axis, $\color{red}{\text{3-axis}}$, and z-axis" should be along the x-axis, $\color{red}{\text{y-axis}}$, and z-axis". [2] Each step must take you **closer** to the origin.  Thus, your journey must consist of $(21)$ steps, $(3)$ of which are along the $x$-axis, and $(7)$ of which are along the $y$-axis, with the remaining $(11)$ steps along the $z$-axis.  Such an interpretation is not obvious from the original problem statement, but is clearly implied from **reverse-engineering** the given answer.

Comment: @user2661923 sorry dear but I can't get you

Comment: The answer given, $\binom{21}{3} \times \binom{18}{7}$ computes the number of ways of choosing $3$ specific numbers out of $21$, and then $18$ specific numbers out of $18$.  Suppose that you had a sequence with $21$ dashes: $-,-,-, \cdots,-,-,-$.  Suppose further that you were going to choose 3 of the positions (dashes), fill in those positions with an $X$, then choose $7$ of the remaining positions, and fill those in with a $Y$, and then fill in the remaining positions with a $Z$.  ...see next comment

Comment: The answer given represents the number of ways of changing the dashes to $X,Y,Z$, subject to the constraint that 3 of the dashes will be changed to an $X$, 7 of the remaining dashes will be changed to a $Y$, and the remaining dashes will be changed to a $Z$.  Therefore, the challenge is to interpret the problem so that the given answer **makes sense**.  The interpretation that I derived is that you are going to take exactly $21$ steps, with 3 of the steps along the $X$-axis, $7$ of the steps along the $Y$-axis, and $11$ of the steps along the $Z$-axis.  ...see next comment

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you

Comment: Given that you are supposed to be *traveling* from $(0,0,0)$ to $(3,7,11)$ such an interpretation is *sensible*.  That is, the $X$ coordinate must increase by $3$ units, the $Y$ coordinate must increase by $7$ units and the $Z$ coordinate must increase by $11$ units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will move a total of $21=3+7+11$ moves in any possible solution from $(0,0,0)$ to $(3,7,11)$. Three of them will be along the x-axis, so let us choose $21 \choose 3$ spots to add the "move along x-axis" move. Now we have $18=21-3$ moves left. Let's choose where we will move along the $y-$axis, which is in total $18 \choose 7$ ways. The remaining $11$ spots will just be "move along z-axis". So in total, the number of ways is

$${21 \choose 3}{18 \choose 7}(1)$$